# Is there something similar to a Bloom filter that allows you to test arbitrary predicates on the set?

Tags: private-set-intersection

As I understand it, if you have a Bloom filter that was generated from the members of a specific set, you can test whether a given bit string is in the set (with some given false positive rate). The idea I had would be to run more complicated predicates on the set, like being able to query whether "there exists a member of the set which is less than target t" using a similar kind of filter. Does such a thing exist and allow you to make these queries without having to have the entire set on hand? How do they work if they exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to answer arbitrary queries, no there is nothing like this. Essentially encoding a set into a Bloom filter is a process of lossy compression so that you gain efficiency in space, but the price you pay is that the data structure can answer only a specific query, i.e. set membership. Other information might have been lost because for this query it is not important.

As such, if you have a specific query in mind, you may be able to design an alternative data structure that satisfies your requirement.